# Is there a browser version of Thunderbird or equivalent

Tags: networking, thunderbird, email, email-client

Is there a "Thunderbird-like" browser application?

I have to allow a user to setup multiple email accounts to sync with a "mailbox" app that has the same functionality as Thunderbird but is based on the browser.

The mailbox app is to be setup on a server at a static IP which can be connected to on the LAN or via a VPN from outside (connection by IP).

I have tried with RoundCube but there were two problems here, I couldn't seem to allow POP (only IMAP) and also it wouldn't display all the accounts in the sidebar as Thunderbird does.

I have to allow POP, IMAP and SMTP in the resulting tool where they can be set by the user

Comment: What about Gmail? It can access other mail servers over POP and IMAP, IIRC, and is already running on Google's servers.

Comment: seems like the obvious choice doesnt it.....my supervisor wants an internal one that we can use POP to keep the mails on the local machine here....

Comment: [Squirrel Mail](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Squirrelmail)?

Comment: that looks promising...I'll look into it, thank you very much

Comment: @muru have you used Squirrel Mail before? I'm just reading over it and I'm not sure its possible to channel mails from multiple addresses into the Squirrel Mail inbox...I could be wrong